# Object is not an object instance en DataGridView

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando traer una lista de SQL y que se cargue en una grilla. Luego de eso, unos campos de esa grilla deben ser de tipo `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, para que el usuario pueda seleccionar opciones según se den los combos. Este es el código que he hecho:

```
public async void ConfigurarGrilla()
{
        try
        {
            var responseArea = await servicio.AreaGetAllAsync();
            var responseEmpresa = await servicio.EmpresaGetAllAsync();

            if (responseArea.IsValid && responseEmpresa.IsValid)
            {
                listaArea = responseArea.Value;
                listaEmpresa = responseEmpresa.Value;

                dgvArticulos.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dtColumn = dgvArticulos.Columns["CodArea"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
                dtColumn.DataSource = listaArea;
                dtColumn.DisplayMember = "CodArea";

                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dtColumn2 = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgvArticulos.Columns["RazonSocial"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
                dtColumn2.DataSource = listaEmpresa;
                dtColumn2.DisplayMember = "RazonSocial";

                LoadDocumento();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(responseArea.ErrorMensaje);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un error " + ex.Message, "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}
```

Los métodos `responseArea.Value` y `responseEmpresa.Value` traen la lista de la BD, la cual sí contiene información cuando hago debug, pero en la linea `dtColumn.DataSource = listaArea` es donde me sale el error

> "object is not an object instance"

No se cual podría ser el error, ya que no he dejado objetos sin instanciar.

Alguno sabrá cual es el posible error?

Comment: Qué tipo de elemento es `listaArea` ? es un error de tipo `Null` , es decir tu variable `listaArea` probablemente sea nula

Answer (score 1):

Te falta indicar el `ValueMember` en ambos `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dtColumn = dgvArticulos.Columns["CodArea"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
dtColumn.DataSource = listaArea;
dtColumn.DisplayMember = "CodArea";
dtColumn.ValueMember = "CodArea";

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dtColumn2 = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgvArticulos.Columns["RazonSocial"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
dtColumn2.DataSource = listaEmpresa;
dtColumn2.DisplayMember = "RazonSocial";
dtColumn2.ValueMember = "RazonSocial";
```

Te dejo un documento de referencia [DataGridView – Parte 4 - Uso del DataGridViewComboBoxColumns](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/01/datagridview-parte-4-uso-del.html)

Comment: Pero el error es antes de esa linea, no cae ahí

Comment: Exactamente en cuál?

Comment: dtColumn.DataSource = listaArea;

Comment: Y qué tipo de dato es `listaArea`?